# Sorting Strings in an Array by Char

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, char

I'm trying to sort a list of strings in array into alphabetical order without using the sort method.

```
public static String[] sortedAdjectives(String[] original)
{
    String[] sortedArray;
    int aValue = 65;
    String word = "";
    sortedArray = new String[25];
    for(int i = 0; i <25; i++)
    {
        original[i]=word;
        char c = word.charAt(0);
        sortedArray[c-aValue]=word;

    }
    return sortedArray;
```

Is my method, and

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner names = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        Scanner adjectives = new Scanner(new File("adjectives.txt"));
        String[] adjectiveArray;
        adjectiveArray = new String[25];
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter<25)
        {
            String in = adjectives.next();
            fixCapitalization(in); //method that fixes capitalization
            adjectiveArray[counter]=in;
            counter++;
        }
        sortedAdjectives(adjectiveArray);
```

Is where I put the items from the file into an array. I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Hmwk.sortedAdjectives(Hmwk.java:56)
    at Hmwk.main(Hmwk.java:24)
```

When I try to run my program and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. If you could point me in the right direction i'd be much appreciative. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your sort method, `word` is the empty string. You're overwriting all values of your input array with this, and trying to access a character that doesn't exist.

Comment: You are making many assumptions about your input strings (several wrong , like the assumption that there are only 25 adjectives.  You strategy should be to implement a method that sorts an array of Strings and call that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `word` initialized as an empty string:

```
String word = "";
```

Then you are calling `charAt(0)` on an empty string. Can't do that. 
Your string needs to be at least longer than 1 character in order to call that method.

Comment: Apart of this, it would be better to add that since `String`s are immutable, calling method `fixCapitalization` should return a `String` and its value should replace the value of `in`, unless this method modifies the `String` interns (which would be really odd).

Comment: But wouldn't original[i]=word; make word equal to the item at the index of 0?

Comment: No, you have to use `word = original[i]` instead. With `original[i]=word` you are assigning the value of `word` to `original[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You made a little mistake in the for loop.
It should probably be word = original[i]; which you did it inversely and makes the word never take the original parameter as reference.

Also a few things to improve here: using arraylist would have better extensibility and avoid erasing repetitive letters.